# Secure REST API deployed on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jersey-2.0, amazon-iam

I have developed a set of Jersey-based REST APIs and deployed them to a Tomcat application server running on Elastic Beanstalk. Our application architecture requires that these REST APIs be accessed from an AngularJS web front end. The web front-end requires user authentication and we want all the accesses to these APIs to be restricted to users who are authenticated. This is a pretty common application architecture pattern.

Now mapping this architectural pattern to AWS services, we configure a Cognito user pool to authenticate users. We map this user pool to an identity pool, to which we attach a policy that allows for access to Beanstalk applications. From here, I don't know what to do next in order to configure secure access to REST APIs. A number of areas in this technical architecture are still not clear to me.

1) How to secure REST APIs on the server (i.e. AWS) side
Because we are using Tomcat container to host Jersey application, the "standard" JEE approach is to declare security constraint in web.xml, as demonstrated in the example below:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/rest/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I am wondering if this role-name "admin" will be ingested by Elastic beanstalk? So if I defined a role "admin" in IAM, and specify the above stanza in web.xml, will Tomcat app server at runtime perform the check? In my application, if I use standard SecurityContext.isUserInRole("admin"), SecurityContext.getUserPrincipal() etc, what kind of values will be returned?

2) web front end service invocation
because we are using AngularJS, the standard approach is to use the built-in $http service to invoke remote REST APIs. Suppose a user logs in through Cognito successfully, and obtains a JWT access token, how should we pass it to the http call to the REST API? Will AWS Javascript SDK automatically add proper HTTP headers to the $http service call or we need to handle this explicitly in our code?

I have researched quite a bit in the Elastic Beanstalk documentation, in particular the section of "integration with IAM service". However, the documentation does not seem to cover my questions above.

I would like to understand:
1) architecturally, how my questions above could be resolved in AWS Beanstalk. I am sure it can be done as it is a common architectural pattern. I just couldn't find the right answer in the documentation.

2) is there a pointer to some sample code? I went through some Java web app samples and built one by myself. However, these samples do not cover my requirements above.

Appreciate if any friend could enlighten me on this topic.

zx999

Comment: Is this application is for administrating AWS resources or for a different business case?

Comment: For a different business case. nothing to do with administrating AWS resources.